# HTTPS Session Cookie 'secure' Attribute Not Set

Tags: security, session, coldfusion-9

One of our clinent did a penetration testing on our site and came back with the following result -

This system is running a web application that does not set the 'secure' attribute for session cookies established over secure (HTTPS) connections. A browser subsequently requesting the same site over a non-secure (HTTP) connection may send the cookie in clear text. An attacker could exploit this to obtain the cookie and hijack the user's session. The following session cookie(s) did not have the 'secure' flag set:

CFID=17608316;  Expires=Sun, 12-Jun-2044 12:18:51 GMT

Path=/; HttpOnly

CFTOKEN=6fc794c5f25867bb-3C16794D...AA8

Expires=Sun, 12-Jun-2044 12:18:51 GMT;

Path=/; HttpOnly

JSESSIONID=083059434...8b1e235

Path=/; HttpOnly

Now, I have very little idea about this, so I googled and I found this link - http://www.petefreitag.com/item/764.cfm.

I found that we already have the `-Dcoldfusion.sessioncookie.httponly=true` value set in jvm.config.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that my scans do not fail.

Comment: `httponly` != `secure`. They're two separate concepts but should usually both be switched on for session cookies.

Comment: Any suggestion on how should I do that.

Comment: As a first guess, I'd look into whether you can also use `coldfusion.sessioncookie.secure=true`.

Comment: Well, from the link I mentioned in the post, yes. My coldfusion server's version is 9.0.2

Comment: update your [local] php.ini and set `session.cookie_secure=1`